# Error in If else loop in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I am writing one code in R. First I am creating one blank column in the data set and I want to assign 0 and 1 value in that column according to some conditions. Here is my code

```
#Creating a empty column in the data file 
Mydata$final <- "";

#To assign 0,1 value in final variable
if(Mydata$Default_Config == "No" & is.na(Mydata$Best_Config)=="TRUE" & (Mydata$AlmostDefaultConfig!=1 | Mydata$AlmostDefaultConfig!=3)){
  Mydata$final <- 1
  }else{
  Mydata$final <- 0  
  }
```

And I am getting this error

```
Warning message:
In if (Mydata$Default_Config == "No" & is.na(Mydata$Best_Config) ==  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How Can I fix this error? Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, since you are relatively new here you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how SO works. StackOverflow is made much more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem, you accept it by clicking the little check mark or upvote a useful answer. You are under absolutely no obligation to do either, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did in fact solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is one of vectorisation. `if` is not vectorised. You are testing multiple values in each comparison in your `if` statement and R is telling you it will only use the first because `if` is not vectorised. You need `ifelse` which is vectorised:

```
ifelse( Mydata$Default_Config == "No" & is.na(Mydata$Best_Config)=="TRUE" & (Mydata$AlmostDefaultConfig!=1 | Mydata$AlmostDefaultConfig!=3) , 1 , 0 )
```

A reproducible example is below. If `x` is `>` 5 and `y` is even then return `1` otherwise return `0`:

```
x <- 1:10
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

y <- seq(1,30,3)
# [1]  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28

x > 5
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

y %% 2 == 0
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

ifelse( x > 5 & y %% 2 == 0 , 1 , 0 )
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to take advantage of `R`'s coercion.  You have a set of conditionals which are vectorizable, and R is happy to convert TRUE/FALSE to 1 / 0,  so you can write it like:

```
Mydata$final <- (  (Mydata$Default_Config == "No") *( is.na(Mydata$Best_Config)=="TRUE") *  (Mydata$AlmostDefaultConfig!=1 +  Mydata$AlmostDefaultConfig!=3))  )
```

(extra parentheses added for clarity) .
Apologies if I fouled up the logic there.

Edit:  My code for the OR won't quite work, since if both sides are TRUE you'd get a big number ("2" :-) ).  Change it to `as.logical((Mydata$AlmostDefaultConfig!=1 +  Mydata$AlmostDefaultConfig!=3))`